# Definition of throughput

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, drugs, chemical-engineering

I wonder what's the exact meaning of throughput in chemistry synthesis, eg. in organic synthesis or production of pharmaceutical products. For instance, what are their units? How are they measured?

I've read one paper mentioning their production methods have a high throughput and production rate (https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/sc/c3sc50859e#!divAbstract).
Are these two concepts the same thing?

Share with me your thoughts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Usually they're synonymous.  Throughput would have the same units e.g. tonnes/day, kg/h.  Basically,  mass or volume per unit time.